# Proper use of flatMap

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

Why I keep getting this error everytime I try an action of my RDD & how to fix it?

```
/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(
```

I've tried to figure out which is the last RDD I can do action on and its ratingByUser, which indicates the problem is in the flatMap.

What I'm trying to do is that I take CSV with (userID,movieID,rating) and I want to create unique combinations of movieID per userID with the rating, but different users can generate the same pair of movieID,ex for this CSV:

1,2000,5

1,2001,2

1,2002,3

2,2000,4

2,2001,1

2,2004,5

I want RDD:

key (2000,2001), value (5,2,1)

key (2000,2002), value (5,3,1)

key (2001,2002), value (2,3,1)

key (2000,2001), value (4,1,1)

key (2000,2004), value (4,5,1)

key (2001,2004), value (1,5,1)

```
# First Map function - gets line and returns key(userID) value(movieID,rating)
def parseLine(line):
  fields=line.split(",")
  userID=int(fields[0])
  movieID=int(fields[1])
  rating=int(fields[2])
  return userID, (movieID,rating)
# Function to create movie unique pairs with ratings
# all pair start with the lowest ID
# returns key (movieIDj,movieIDi) & value (rating-j,rating-i,1)
# the 1 in value is added in order to count number of ratings in the reduce

def createPairs(userRatings):
  pairs=[]
  for i1 in range(len(userRatings[1])-1):
    for i2 in range(i1+1,len(userRatings[1])):
      if userRatings[i1][0]<userRatings[1][i2][0]:
        pairs.append(((userRatings[1][i1][0],userRatings[1][i2][0]),(userRatings[1][i1][1],userRatings[1][i2][1],1)))
      else:
        pairs.append(((userRatings[1][i2][0],userRatings[1][i1][0]),(userRatings[1][i2][1],userRatings[1][i1][1],1)))
  return pairs

# Create SC object from the ratings file
lines = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/dvmlbdnj1487603982330/ratings.csv")
# Map lines to Key(userID),Value(movieID,rating)
movieRatings = lines.map(parseLine)
# Join all rating by same user into one key
# (UserID1,(movie1,rating1)),(UserID1,(movie2,rating2)) --> UserID1,[(movie1,rating1),(movie2,rating2)]
ratingsPerUser = movieRatings.groupByKey()
# activate createPairs func
# We use flatMap, since each user have different number of ratings --> different number pairs
pairsOfMovies = ratingsPerUser.flatMap(createPairs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is function passed to `flatMap` not `flatMap`.
 Group by key returns iterator:

- It cannot be traversed multiple times
- It cannot be indexed.

Convert to list first:

```
ratingsPerUser.mapValues(list).flatMap(createPairs)
```